# I want to return data from dynamodb when the key matches

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

```
**I want to return the data key values but it is not working. Please help me. The main concept of this method is when this is invoke dal is the keyword and it fetches that key values from the dynamodb. For that i used global also but not updating that global variable also.
```

I tried returning the value from the callback, as well as assigning the result to a local variable inside the function and returning that one, but none of those ways actually return the response (they all return undefined or whatever the initial value of the variable result is).**

```
function getLocation(){
    let a=[];
    const documentClient = new AWSS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:"us-east-2"});
        const params = {
            TableName : "ProductLocation1",
            Key :{
                Product_Name : 'dal'
            }
        };
        documentClient.get(params,(err,data)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log('error is',err);
            }
            console.log('data is : ',data);
            global.a=Object.keys(data);
        });
        return global.a;
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention the coming result in callback for err or data as well?

Comment: There is no error, but it is not return the data, It return undefine

Comment: Did you please confirm that the data you are trying to get is available in your table because the data will come undefined, if nothing get's from dynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    const result = await documentClient.get(params).promise();
} catch (error) {
    // handle error
}
```

You could get the result using the promise & await rather than the callback function. In this way, you don't need to store them in a local variable.

Comment: I am getting parsing error : Unexpected token documentClient

Comment: Does your function has permission to access dynamodb?

Comment: Yes all permissions are given